# what's the correct way to add translations defined in xml to Odoo through .po files?

Tags: xml, odoo-10

i have some terms defined in xml (english terms), and i want to translate them throught .po files (to frensh language).

```
went to Settings > Translations > Load a Translation, i selected Frensh language and checked the box Overwrite Existing Terms, then clicked on Load button.

After that, i refreshed the browser, then went to Settings > Translations > Application Terms > Synchronize Terms, selected frensh language and clicked on Update. then refreshed again.
```

but i can't find the terms after the export translation in the .po file, even in the Settings > Application Terms > translated terms i can't find them here.

how i can solve this problem ?.

Answer (score 1):

**Hello @Mehdi**

1. To translate your module, First thing you need to do is make a
   folder in you customModule

   **Folder name must be**:- i18n
2. Activate your language: (Go to translations/languages/search_your_language/and activate it.)

   - Now to go to you localserver >  go to Settings/Translations/Import-Export/Export Translation(The import/export menu doesn't showed up without debug mode)
   - In export translation wizard select your language / Select file format: **PO File**/ then select your custom module in next field / and finally then click on **Export** button.
   - Once Export completed next wizard will showed up with file where file name showed up like this:- language_code.po(For ex:- **es_US.po**)
   - Click on the file to download it.
   - Once download completed, place this file into you **i18n** folder.
   - Now go into that file their are your sentences, those are used in your module.(Find msgid and msgstr for each and every sentence)
   - For ex:- msgid "All Table Booked?"   (Your sentence in native language)
         msgstr "Todas las mesas reservadas?" (Translate in your desired language.)
   - Once all sentence translated by your end, please save this file.
   - Finally go to Settings/Translations once again, Their is a menu :- **Load Translations** >> Click on the menu >> Select the language >> Then in next Field (name:- **Overwrite Existing Terms**) Tick this box. >>  Click on the load button.
   - Once Load completed it will automatically refresh your window.
   - Now go to your login user's preference to change your language(change it and refresh it you'll see everything in your languaage with you custom module.)
   - If you change any sentence in your custom module please follow all steps that are defined above(that we have done).

Comment: thank you for your answer which covers everything. I did all that and it's work but not for all words Unfortunately. 
My problem is: i created some category of product in xml file [data] and i want to translate those category but they are not displayed in the .po file. any advice to give me. thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok then please make new one for you word,


#. module: your_module_name
#: model:model_name,name:your_module_name.data_file_xml_id
msgid "Your_word"
msgstr "translate it in your desired language"
If you want any reference then go to account module in odoo-addons you'll find data file and search any data_xml_id in any .po file , you'll get the idea.